# What is different between "temp = self.head" and "self.head"

Tags: python

I had try the code for "updating_value" inside a linked list as following:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, dataval):
        self.dataval = dataval
        self.ref = None    # linked pointer**


class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None    # Node('My List:')
        self.tail = None
    
    def push(self, data):
        new_node = Node(data)
        if self.__is_empty__():
            self.head = self.tail = new_node
        else:
            new_node.ref = self.head
            self.head = new_node
    
    def update_value(self, a, b):
        if self.__is_empty__():
            return
        else:
            temp = self.head
            while temp:
                if temp.dataval == a:
                    temp.dataval = b
                temp = temp.ref
```

Any time I use this syntax inside update_value function: `temp = self.head`, it shall give correct output. However this code:

```
    def update_value(self, a, b):
        if self.__is_empty__():
            return
        else:
            while self.head:
                if self.head.dataval == a:
                    self.head.dataval = b
                self.head = self.head.ref
```

It causes the problem same as infinite loop or code is not executed.

Please help in clarifying this issue. Thank you all for your supports!

Answer (score 2):

The original code doesn't modify what the name `self.head` points to; it just grabs that reference to a `temp`orary variable and walks it, never touching the actual `self.head` reference.

Your modified code modifies `self.head` directly, eventually making it point to `None`.

Comment: Thank you for your clarification and I think I can understand now, appreciate your answer